# Sending email when implementing ShouldQueue or using the queue() method results in a Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\Factory, null given for Lumen 5.8

Tags: redis, lumen, laravel-queue, laravel-valet, laravel-5.8

I'm new on Lumen and currently learning on using **Lumen 5.8**. Recently, my app that I'm developing requires implementing **ShouldQueue** or the **queue()** method when **sending an email** for various purpose. So I followed the [instructions on the official page](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.8/mail) of setting up Mail on the Lumen 5.8 and I also saw the **Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\MailQueue::class** alias being setup on app.php. Unfortunately, sending email without queueing was fine except for sending when implementing the queue method and / or ShouldQueue. Are they another instruction on how to make queueing mail possible on the Lumen 5.8? Below is the error produced when trying to push the mail into the queue.

```html
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Mail\Mailable::queue() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\Factory, null given
```

Thanks really much !!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm too late but here's the solution.
Add `$app->make('queue');` after `$app->withEloquent();` in `config/app.php`